# Error message in Dataflow -- "Previous watemark was unknown"

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

Google Dataflow Java process generates tons of such warnings ("Previous watemark was unknown..."). What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.Timing.html#UNKNOWN) on this yet?

Comment: Please, guide me where I must apply panes to? A small example plz

Comment: This is an internal debug message that's usually harmless, so we'll decrease its verbosity level. Did this happen at the beginning of the pipeline or while it has already been running for a while? Were there any other anomalies in this pipeline? (if yes, a job ID would help debugging)

Comment: @jkff This happened at the beginning of the pipeline only. Yes, there were other anomalies, e.g. error about broken file system ext4.

Comment: It is expected at the beginning of the pipeline, so everything seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is system-level message with an inappropriately high verbosity level.  We'll decrease that, and you can safely ignore it.